# Unable to understand the reason of my str.translate line

Tags: python, character, translate

*I am trying to learn the basics of Python through swaroopch's "A Byte of Python".*

Under chapter "Input and Output" there is an exercise where I have to come up with the solution on how to remove the punctuation and space from an input string.

I can translate characters to spaces, but I am unable to translate them to nothing.

```
    something = something.lower().translate(str.maketrans(',. ',''))
ValueError: the first two maketrans arguments must have equal length
```

However, somehow this worked:

```
something = something.lower().translate(str.maketrans('', '', ' ,.'))
```

Can you please break it down, or tell me how it should have been done?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation for `str.maketrans`?

Comment: The `maketrans()` documentation says "If there are two arguments, they must be strings of equal length", so you'll need to pass a single dictionary since you're replacing the characters with nothing (so the two string arguments couldn't possibly have the same length).

Comment: I did readt the documentation, but before that i saw online that it can be done without a dictionary. It does work with a dictionary tho, so i will give you credit since i didnt follow the documentation which fixed the issue. However what i am trying to understand, and i think i didnt format the question well, is how did the secound code worked for me i.e. remove punctuation and spaces since the string for maketrans doesnt really make sense for me